# Super hub 3.0 unable to communicate with Chromecast

Tags: networking, wireless-router, cable-modem, adsl-router, chromecast

I recently got Virgin Media installed and their SuperHub 3.0 which is not able to communicate with my Chromecast, also my kodi/osmc does not show up in yatse either.

This all worked fine when I was with Talk Talk and using my Technicolor tg582n. So I decided to put the SuperHub into modem mode and connected it to the wan port of the Technicolor router but it was not getting an internet connection.

I am not very experienced in networking but I think the problem is that the Technicolor is looking for PPPoE/a but virgin uses docsis. If this is the problem can I install a firmware or telnet into the router and change the configuration to get it to work?

If anyone knows how to fix the super hub or to get it working with the Technicolor router that would be great. Thanks.

Note: just thought I would add that uPnP is enabled on the SuperHub and I have tried disabling the firewall to see if that was the issue.

Comment: [Chromecast can't connect to internet on Virgin Superhub (1 and 2)](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromecast/6x0eRPxmVqk)

Comment: I have read that post already. No joy.

Comment: Whatever. The problem is with the Superhub/Chromecast config. You cannot connect an ADSL modem to a Cable Modem and get it working how you want. The best you can do is connect the ADSL modem via a LAN connection and use it as a switch. That won't solve the Chromecast issue,

Comment: So does that mean that I have to buy a cable router and connect that to the super hub modem?

Comment: Look at the manuals for your devices. The superhub has ethernet ports as outputs. The Technicolor gateway has a DSL port. You cannot plug an ethernet cable into a DSL port. You can plug an ethernet cable into an ethernet port on the Technicolor gateway but that makes it a switch not a router. Like I said above that will not fix the Superhub/Chromecast issue. You have to fix that in the Superhub. Putting the Superhub into modem modem will not fix this.

Comment: Please call Virgin Media support. They should be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Called Virgin Media (150 from landline) and they upgraded my superhub3 firmware to 9.1.88T. Now both Chromecast v1 and v2 are working fine.